# Application has crashed when deny permission in Setting App Info

Tags: android, android-permissions

My Application's flow: Activity A -> open activity B

Activity A sets value for static variable (variable *sState*)what activity B needs to create.

Step 1: Activity B is already in foreground. Push it into background.

Step 2: open app info setting and revoke any permission.

Step 3: Open activity B from recent-screen, activity B appears and crashed occurs because the sState is not initialized

In my android monitor, when deny permission, my application's process is terminated.

What happens when app permission is revoked ?
So, I already know that using static variable is not good choice. But If I want activity A appears instead of B in step 3. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application losts all static variable when deny any permission from device settings in application runtime. You should use saveInstanceState() to preserve your static value in activity B.

```
private static final String STATE_KEY_STATIC_VALUE = "state_key_static_value";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(STATE_KEY_STATIC_VALUE, sState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sState = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_KEY_STATIC_VALUE);
}
```

Or you can pass value from A activity to B activity through intent. If you use intent to pass any value, then your value will be preserved automatically.

And when deny permission from device settings, foreground activity will be shown again. There is no way to show other activity.